# How to invert a function that contains a sign function?

Tags: inverse-function

I have the following function: $$f(w,y-x) = \operatorname{sgn}[y-x]|y-x|^w$$, where $w \geq 0, (y-x) \in[-1,1]$, which results in $f(w,y-x) \in [-1,1]$.

I would like to find its inverse function with respect to $x$. But I got stuck when trying to invert the sign function and the absolute function. Can you show me how to invert the function please ?
$$x = ???$$

Comment: What is the domain and codomain of $f$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\text{sgn}(f) = \text{sgn}(y-x)$ and $|y-x|^w = |f|$, hence $|y-x|=|f|^{1/w}$, hence $y-x = \text{sgn}(f)|f|^{1/w}$, hence
\begin{equation}
x = y - \text{sgn}(f)|f|^{1/w}
\end{equation}